# Creating an instance of a python object error - how to call the super method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, init, super

If I have a class defined as such in one file (called gui.py), (where QtWidgets is an imported module (PyQt5))

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__(self)

        # other regular stuff in init...
```

How in another file do I create an instance of this object? i.e. when I do the following,

```
import gui
window = gui.Window()
```

I get error "super-class__init__() of type Window was never called". Also when I try

```
window = gui.Window.super().__init__()
```

I get the error type Object 'Window' has no attribute 'super'.

Comment: super().__init__(...)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: @RamazanPolat I tried this but still got an error message saying that Window has no attribute 'super' (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

(grabbed from https://pythonspot.com/category/pyqt5/)